# generate a new list with a button in tkinter with variables used later error python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have created a program which picks 4 random songs from a list when you press the 'New List' button. These songs will then be assigned to variables and the 'Play Song' buttons will play the song and you will have to enter your guess and press submit.

Now I have defined the command 'newlist' and it works fine it make a new list of the songs from the main list but the problem is I cannot carry the song name generated from that `random.sample` later on in the program.

Full code:

```py
from playsound import playsound
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

master=tk.Tk()
master.title("Song Guessing Game")
master.config(bg="royalblue1")

background="royalblue1"
background2="ghost white"
background3="blue2"
bg4="steelblue"

#SONG LISTS:
songs=["big chungus.mp3","candyland.mp3","a92 fumez.mp3","on and on.mp3","troll song.mp3"]


def newsongs():
    newsongs=random.sample(songs,4)
    song1,song2,song3,song4=newsongs

    song1name=song1[:-4].upper()
    song2name=song2[:-4].upper()
    song3name=song3[:-4].upper()
    song4name=song4[:-4].upper()

    print("Song List:",song1,song2,song3,song4)


tk.Button(master,text="New Songs",bg=bg4,relief="solid",fg="black",command=newsongs).grid()


def play1():
    playsound(song1)

def play2():
    playsound(song2)

def play3():
    playsound(song3)

def play4():
    playsound(song4)



tk.Label(master,text="Song Guesser",font="Verdanda 20 underline bold",bg=background,fg="black",relief="solid").grid(row=0,column=1)

tk.Button(master,text="Play Song 1",command=play1,font="Verdanda 15 bold",bg=bg4).grid(row=1,column=0)
tk.Button(master,text="Play Song 2",command=play2,font="Verdanda 15 bold",bg=bg4).grid(row=2,column=0)
tk.Button(master,text="Play Song 3",command=play3,font="Verdanda 15 bold",bg=bg4).grid(row=3,column=0)
tk.Button(master,text="Play Song 4",command=play4,font="Verdanda 15 bold",bg=bg4).grid(row=4,column=0)

guess1=tk.Entry(master,bg=background3,fg="black",font="Verdanda 15")
guess2=tk.Entry(master,bg=background3,fg="black",font="Verdanda 15")
guess3=tk.Entry(master,bg=background3,fg="black",font="Verdanda 15")
guess4=tk.Entry(master,bg=background3,fg="black",font="Verdanda 15")

guess1.grid(row=1,column=1)
guess2.grid(row=2,column=1)
guess3.grid(row=3,column=1)
guess4.grid(row=4,column=1)


def submit():
    def check(guess,expected,label):
        if guess.get().strip().upper()==expected:
            label.config(text="Correct",fg="green")
        else:
            label.config(text="Incorrect",fg="red")

    check(guess1,song1name,_status1_)
    check(guess2,song2name,_status2_)
    check(guess3,song3name,_status3_)
    check(guess4,song4name,_status4_)

    



_status1_=tk.Label(master,font="Verdanda 15 bold",bg=background2)
_status2_=tk.Label(master,font="Verdanda 15 bold",bg=background2)
_status3_=tk.Label(master,font="Verdanda 15 bold",bg=background2)
_status4_=tk.Label(master,font="Verdanda 15 bold",bg=background2)

_status1_.grid(row=1,column=3)
_status2_.grid(row=2,column=3)
_status3_.grid(row=3,column=3)
_status4_.grid(row=4,column=3)

_status1_.config()

tk.Button(master,text="Submit Score",command=submit).grid(row=5,column=1)


master.mainloop()
```

When running this I get an error `File "v2.5.py", line 73, in submit check(guess1,song1name,_status1_) NameError: name 'song1name' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

song1name is a local variable to the `newsongs` function. You need to declare the song1name and the other song#name variables in a global context, or else store it elsewhere.

You can initialize them all at the start of the file with something like `song1name = song2name = song3name = song4name = None`, but this is a long way to go about it.

You might have a better result declaring a `songnames = []` list, either declared outside of any function or passed into `submit` as an argument. Then set the songs you choose as the four items in it, and access those later in the `submit` function.

```
songlist = []

def newsongs():
    songlist = [song[:4].upper() for song in random.sample(songs,4)]

...

    check(guess1,songlist[0],_status1_)
    check(guess1,songlist[1],_status2_)
    etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because those `songXname` are local variables inside `newsongs()` function which cannot be accessed outside the function.  You can declare them as `global` to fix the issue.

However you don't need those `songXname` at all, just use `songs`:

```py
def newsongs():
    random.shuffle(songs) # shuffle the song list randomly
    print("Song List:", songs[:4])

...

def play1():
    playsound(songs[0])

def play2():
    playsound(songs[1])

def play3():
    playsound(songs[2])

def play4():
    playsound(songs[3])

...

def submit():
    def check(guess,expected,label):
        expected = expected.split(".")[0].upper()
        if guess.get().strip().upper()==expected:
            label.config(text="Correct",fg="green")
        else:
            label.config(text="Incorrect",fg="red")

    check(guess1,songs[0],_status1_)
    check(guess2,songs[1],_status2_)
    check(guess3,songs[2],_status3_)
    check(guess4,songs[3],_status4_)
```